WebRTC Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable
I'm making a website that can livestream via webRTC. One client will publish their video from the camera and send it to the server. Another client who wants to watch will transmit the correct License of that livestream to the server to connect with each other and watch the lives. but now when another client wants to watch live, there is an error:
DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable
I not good at javascript so i dont know what wrong with this code. Can someone help me ?
client join livesteam
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Join Live Stream</title>
    <script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Join Live Stream</h1>
    <input type="text" id="licenseInput" placeholder="Enter License">
    <button id="joinButton">Join Stream</button>
    <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay playsinline></video>
    <script>
        let peerConnection;
        const signalingServerUrl = "http://localhost:8080";

        document.getElementById('joinButton').addEventListener('click', joinStream);

        async function joinStream() {
            const license = document.getElementById('licenseInput').value;
            if (!license) {
                alert("Please enter a license");
                return;
            }

            try {
                const response = await fetch(`${signalingServerUrl}/watch/${license}`);
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Failed to receive offer');
                }
                const data = await response.json();
                await handleOffer(data.offer);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error joining stream:', error);
            }
        }

        async function handleOffer(offer) {
            try {
                if (!peerConnection) {
                    peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();
                    peerConnection.addEventListener('icecandidate', handleICECandidate);
                    peerConnection.addEventListener('track', handleTrack);
                }

                // Check if RTCPeerConnection is in a stable state
                if (peerConnection.signalingState !== 'stable') {
                    console.log('Not in stable state, postponing setRemoteDescription');
                    // Handle the state as needed, perhaps by queuing the offer for later
                    return;
                }

                // Set remote description
                await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));

                // Create answer
                const answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
                await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);

                // Send answer to signaling server
                const answerData = {
                    license: document.getElementById('licenseInput').value,
                    sdp: peerConnection.localDescription
                };

                const response = await fetch(`${signalingServerUrl}/answer/${document.getElementById('licenseInput').value}`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(answerData)
                });

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Failed to send answer');
                }

                console.log('Answer sent successfully');
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error handling offer:', error);
            }
        }

        function handleICECandidate(event) {
            console.log('ICE candidate:', event.candidate);
        }

        function handleTrack(event) {
            const remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');
            if (remoteVideo.srcObject !== event.streams[0]) {
                remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0];
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

client publish livestream
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Publish Live Stream</title>
    <script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Publish Live Stream</h1>
    <video id="localVideo" autoplay playsinline></video>
    <button id="startButton">Start Publishing</button>
    <button id="stopButton" disabled>Stop Publishing</button>
    <script>
        let localStream;
        let peerConnection;
        const signalingServerUrl = "http://localhost:8080";

        document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener('click', startPublishing);
        document.getElementById('stopButton').addEventListener('click', stopPublishing);

        async function startPublishing() {
            try {
                localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false });
                document.getElementById('localVideo').srcObject = localStream;

                peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();
                localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => peerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream));

                console.log("Creating offer...");
                const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
                console.log("Setting local description...");
                await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);

                const offerData = {
                    license: "49B1-3220", 
                    sdp: peerConnection.localDescription
                };

                console.log("Sending offer to signaling server...");
                const response = await fetch(signalingServerUrl + "/publish", {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(offerData)
                });

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Failed to send offer to server');
                }

                console.log("Offer sent successfully!");
                console.log(offerData)
                document.getElementById('startButton').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('stopButton').disabled = false;
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error starting publishing:', error);
            }
        }

        function stopPublishing() {
            localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
            document.getElementById('localVideo').srcObject = null;
            peerConnection.close();

            document.getElementById('startButton').disabled = false;
            document.getElementById('stopButton').disabled = true;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

and signalling sever in GO
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/pion/webrtc/v3"
)

type OfferRequest struct {
    License            string                    `json:"license"`
    SessionDescription webrtc.SessionDescription `json:"sdp"`
}

type Stream struct {
    License string
    PC      *webrtc.PeerConnection
}

var (
    streams      = make(map[string]*Stream)
    streamsMutex sync.Mutex
)

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    config := cors.DefaultConfig()
    config.AllowOrigins = []string{"*"}
    router.Use(cors.New(config))

    router.POST("/publish", handlePublish)
    router.GET("/watch/:license", handleWatch)
    router.POST("/answer/:license", handleAnswer)

    fmt.Println("Server started at :8080")
    log.Fatal(router.Run(":8080"))
}

func handlePublish(c *gin.Context) {
    var offerRequest OfferRequest
    if err := c.BindJSON(&offerRequest); err != nil {
        log.Println("Error decoding offer request:", err)
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": "Bad Request"})
        return
    }
    offer := offerRequest.SessionDescription
    license := offerRequest.License
    fmt.Println("License:", license)

    peerConnection, err := webrtc.NewPeerConnection(webrtc.Configuration{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error creating peer connection:", err)
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Internal Server Error"})
        return
    }

    peerConnection.OnICECandidate(func(candidate *webrtc.ICECandidate) {
        if candidate != nil {
            fmt.Println("ICE Candidate:", candidate)
        }
    })

    if err = peerConnection.SetRemoteDescription(offer); err != nil {
        log.Println("Error setting remote description:", err)
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Internal Server Error"})
        return
    }

    answer, err := peerConnection.CreateAnswer(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error creating answer:", err)
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Internal Server Error"})
        return
    }

    if err = peerConnection.SetLocalDescription(answer); err != nil {
        log.Println("Error setting local description:", err)
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Internal Server Error"})
        return
    }

    streamsMutex.Lock()
    streams[license] = &Stream{
        License: license,
        PC:      peerConnection,
    }
    streamsMutex.Unlock()

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"answer": answer})
}

func handleWatch(c *gin.Context) {
    license := c.Param("license")

    streamsMutex.Lock()
    stream, found := streams[license]
    streamsMutex.Unlock()

    if !found {
        log.Println("Stream not found for license:", license)
        c.JSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"error": "Stream not found"})
        return
    }

    answer := struct {
        Type  string                    `json:"type"`
        Offer webrtc.SessionDescription `json:"offer"`
    }{
        Type:  "offer",
        Offer: *stream.PC.LocalDescription(),
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, answer)
}

func handleAnswer(c *gin.Context) {
    var answer webrtc.SessionDescription
    if err := c.BindJSON(&answer); err != nil {
        log.Println("Error decoding answer request:", err)
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": "Bad Request"})
        return
    }

    license := c.Param("license")

    streamsMutex.Lock()
    stream, found := streams[license]
    streamsMutex.Unlock()

    if !found {
        log.Println("Stream not found for license:", license)
        c.JSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"error": "Stream not found"})
        return
    }

    if err := stream.PC.SetRemoteDescription(answer); err != nil {
        log.Println("Error setting remote description:", err)
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Internal Server Error"})
        return
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": "Answer processed successfully"})
}



This question is similar to: Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I've check but its cannot solve my problem. My signalling sever code using GO, and client can publish livestream or join livestream by WebRTC.

You may refer to the following URL for using the "Perfect negotiation" pattern to create a WebRTC connection:
https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#perfect-negotiation-example

I think negotiation logic is wrong.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Perfect_negotiation#the_perfect_negotiation_logic
As far as I know, caller should first send its SDP that contains possible codecs, but you request Callee's first.
let makingOffer = false;

pc.onnegotiationneeded = async () => {
  try {
    makingOffer = true;
    await pc.setLocalDescription();
    signaler.send({ description: pc.localDescription });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    makingOffer = false;
  }
};

If you set LocalDescription, signalingstatechange event will be triggered.
switch(pc.signalingState) {
  case 'have-local-offer': {
    requestAndSetRemoteSDP();
    break;
  }
  // sth
}

and then request Remote SDP like that.
